# How do I disable the Stackdriver Logging agent in a cluster?

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine

Our project recently migrated away from Stackdriver Logging. However, I cannot figure out how to get rid of the `fluentd-cloud-logging-*` pods in the `kube-system` namespace. If I delete the individual pods, they come right back.

How do I kill them off for good?

It's not clear to me how they're getting recreated; there is certainly no DaemonSet bringing them back.

I already set `monitoringService` to `none` in the configuration described by `gcloud container clusters describe`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fluentd-cloud-logging pods in the kube-system namespace are defined in the `/etc/kubernetes/manifests/` folder of each host machine; that is, they're defined using the [Static Pods](https://kubernetes.io/docs/admin/static-pods/) mechanism.

As of this time, there's no way to change the setting globally. As a workaround, though, I can just delete the file in the manifests folder on each node, using something like the [startup script pod](https://github.com/kubernetes/contrib/blob/master/startup-script/startup-script.yml). When the file is deleted, the pod will be deleted as well.

(Thanks to GCP support for this answer.)

Comment: For anyone coming back to this after Nov 28th 2017 : You can now disable Stackdriver logging for the cluster simply by Editing the cluster and setting Stackdriver logging to "Disabled". This is a recent addition.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on your Kubernetes Master version.

1. From your Google Cloud Dashboard, go to [Kubernetes Clusters](https://console.cloud.google.com/kubernetes/list)
2. Choose your cluster from the list
3. Click on Edit
4. Check your Master version and based on that, choose one of the following

## 1.12.7 or earlier (Legacy Logging)

It is possible to disable Logging by choosing `Legacy Logging: Disabled`.

[image: Disable Legacy Logging]

## 1.14 or earlier (Kubernetes Engine Monitoring)

You have two options:

1. Switch to Legacy Logging and disable logging
2. Disable all logging and monitoring. Bear in mind that this will disable all data collection. Google also warns: Dragons ahead.

[image: Disable Kubernetes Engine Monitoring]

## 1.15.7 or Later

You can select `System logging and monitoring only (beta)`. This will stop log collection from application but system monitoring and log collection will remain. Here is the description of what system logs:

When the system-only option is selected, the following logs are collected:

> All pods running in namespaces kube-system, istio-system,
>   knative-serving,gke-system, and config-management-system.
>
> Key services that are not containerized including docker/containerd
>   runtime, kubelet, kubelet-monitor, node-problem-detector, and
>   kube-container-runtime-monitor.
>
> The node’s serial ports output, if the VM instance metadata
>   serial-port-logging-enable is set to true.

Source: https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/kubernetes-engine/installing

Comment: Is there a way of disabling stackdriver when creating a cluster using the `gcloud` command line utility?

Comment: I haven't tried it myself but it seems there is a flag to enable stackdriver. https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/container/clusters/create#--enable-stackdriver-kubernetes