# How to disable Stackdriver Logging?

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I have a Google Cloud Platform project where I use Kubernetes to deploy my apps, but I have noticed on my billing that Stackdriver Logging costs too much for me and I don't really need logging right now.

So, does anyone know how can I disable the Stackdriver Logging API in my clusters?

Comment: [How do I disable the Stackdriver Logging agent in a cluster?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61345745/811008)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can disable logging in several ways:

- Disabling like [in here](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/logging#disabling_logging).
- Doing this [old workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42447388/3058302).